# TYPE distinguish between list of lists and list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, types

I am writing a python def which will take an input argument of either type: [(list of tuples)] or [[list of lists]], and it would lead to different handling methods.  It looks like they both have the type of 'list' (). How to distinguish between these two different kind of data that the user may input ?

Thanks.

Comment: They are both "lists", so of course they have the same type.  You would need to inspect every element, because maybe someone sends a list of mixed lists and tuples.

Comment: Do you actually need to differentiate between a list of lists and a list of tuples?  Probably not, right?

Answer (score 5):

Get the type of the first item in the list.

```
if isinstance(x, list) and len(x) != 0:
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        # Do stuff for list of lists
    elif isinstance(x[0], tuple):
        # Do stuff for list of tuples
```

Of course, make sure `x` is a `list` and that it has an item in it.

Also, this breaks down if you get a list with mixed lists and tuples.  It might be better to make the distinction later, and treat the containing list the same in both cases if you can.  Otherwise, you need to inspect every item in the list.

Comment: _isinstance_ is cleaner

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is list of list or list of tuples:

```
def doit(value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        if isinstance(value[0], list):
            print 'process list'
        elif isinstance(value[0], tuple):
            print 'process tuple'
```